# qml lock Item from the offset when the keyboard is displayed

Tags: qt, qml

Is there a way to make the page so that when the keyboard is displayed, not the entire page is shifted up? In fact, I need to make a toolbar that does not moved by keyboard.

Comment: Which keyboard? There are several virtual/software keyboards.

Comment: software keyboard